# Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, xml

I keep getting this error when I do `xml.LoadXml(stringName)`, where stringName is xml data I'm getting from the database. However, if I copy and paste the all the xml from the database and assign stringName to equal the xml directly, it will all work fine.

So this works:

```
string stringName = "<... some xml data ...>"
xml.LoadXml(stringName)
```

But this doesnt:

```
xml.LoadXml(stringName) <- stringName is passed to my method
```

Any ideas why typing out the xml directly will work but assigning it from the database doesnt? If I print the string from the database it shows the correct xml on the screen(its where I copy and pasted from).

EDIT:

Okay, so the xml is stored as an xml datatype.

If(using MVC 2), I do:

```
<%=Model.ShowXml%>
```

I will see the full(and correct) xml on the screen.

Now, ShowXml is a string in the model. Should I have it as a different data type? I'm using automapper in my controller to map my model to my database.

Comment: Are you sure that `stringName` is what you think it is?

Comment: Sounds like it may be an encoding issue. What datatype is storing the xml in the database and what database/access library are you using? Some database access code might help :)

Comment: Are you sure what you copied and what was queried are identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would try:

```
string xmlFromDB = ... fetch XML from DB
Console.WriteLine((int)xmlFromDB[0]);
```

If the output is not 60 (decimal [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) code for `<`) you probably have an encoding issue. Could be because you have incorrectly stored the XML in the database or you could be fetching it incorrectly. Though to say with the level of details you have shown in your question.

Comment: okay, I got 38. I think its because the xml data is stored as an xml type, but i'm assigning it right to a string. would that be it?

Comment: @Tonnie, 38 is ASCII for `&`. You definitely have some encoding issue. Could be the way you are reading it. As I said though to say from the level of details you have provided.

Comment: @Tonnie, when you do `<%=Model.ShowXml%>` you are seeing the *correct* XML on the screen because everything is HTML encoded. For example `<` is converted to `&lt;` which is its HTML entity. This is obviously invalid XML. Have you tried HTML decoding the string value you have before passing it to the `LoadXml` method?